# change check-in setting for entire project

Tags: tfs

We have a TFS server setup with three projects. Recently we wanted to change TFS so that code checkins had to have a Work Item Number associated with it. I was able to accomplish this by:

In Visual Studio

```
Team -> Team Project Settings -> Source Control
```

Then select checkin policy tab and add "Require associated work items."

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181281%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

The problem is that it only seemed to work for one of the three (the first one) projects. I've tried Team -> Team Project Collection Settings but there is no option for the checkin policy.

I've also tried highlighting the individual project I wanted to change the check in policy but they all seem to show that the checkin policy has been setup correctly for requiring a work item with code checkin.

How can I change the settings that all the projects on the TFS server have the same checkin policy?

Comment: When you say "Projects" do you mean Visual Studio projects (.csproj files), or do you mean "Team Projects"?

Comment: I mean't to say Team projects

Comment: And what do you mean by "subprojects"? Please update your question to clarify.

Comment: I updated the question. The subprojects are just projects on the TFS server, wasn't sure how to phrase it correctly at first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check-in policies are set per team project. There is no global meaning collection or server level way of setting and enforcing check-in policies on all of existing and future team projects. You will need to add appropriate check-in policies for each and every team project you need using the project level source control setting in Team Explorer. You can also use TFS client SDK to automate that process to iterate all or some of the existing team projects and add check-in policies. Another option is to take advantage of TFS server side events to get notified when a new team project is created and add check-in policies in response in case of automating the configuration of check-in policies for newly created team projects.

[Team Foundation Server Event Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc507647.aspx#S3)

Comment: Using Source Control Explorer I select the 3rd project then goto `Team -> Team Project Settings -> Source Control` but the project is always the first one. I don't know how to tell Source Control Explorer to select the 3rd project. Any Ideas?

Comment: You need to switch team projects. You cannot do it from source control explorer. You need to use the team explorer to switch team projects then go to the source control settings.